# Expectation value and variance; exercise

Tags: probability, statistics, solution-verification

> A coin is tossed repeatedly with a probability $p$ of landing on tails. If the result of a toss is head, then the coin is tossed again, otherwise not. For each completed toss, the player gets one scratch card. Let $X$ be the number of received scratch cards. For each card, there is a probability $q$ of winning 1 dollar. Let $Y$ be the amount of money that you've won. Find $E(X),Var(x),E(Y),Var(Y)$.

My attempt:

- $X$ follows the geometric distribution with success rate $p$ (where a success is tossing tails). Therefore $E(X)=1/p$ and $Var(X)=(1-p)/p^2$.
- For one scratch card, we have $E(Y_1)=q$ and $Var(Y_1)=q-q^2$. The cards can be seen as i.i.d. random variables, which means that $E(\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i)=nq$ and $Var(\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i)=n(q-q^2).$ The number of cards is a random variable and therefore $E(Y), Var(Y)$ depend on that number. If $X=n$, then we have $E(Y)=nq$ and $Var(Y)=n(q-q^2)$.

I'm not sure about the calculations for $Y$, because they depend on the value of $X$. So should I say $E(Y|X=n)=nq$. But then, how do I find $E(Y)$?

Thanks.

Comment: $E[Y]=qE[X]$ by the [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation).  Use the [law of total variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance) for $Var(Y)$

Comment: Thank you very much! So the variance would be $Var(Y)=E[Var(Y|X)]+Var[E(Y|X)] = E[X(q-q^2)]+q^2Var(E[X])$. The last term is the variance of a constant and thus equal to zero. So, $Var(Y)=(q-q^2)E[X]$?

Comment: No, because $E(Y | X)$ is not constant, therefore its variance is non-zero. $E(Y|X)=qX$, therefore $Var[E(Y|X)]=q^2 Var(X)$.

Comment: Thanks. I have one more question regarding this exercise. It has to do with the log-likelihood function and MLE for $p$ and $q$. Suppose that we have $n$ independent observations where we know both the results of the coin tosses and the total amount of acquired money. I need to find MLE's for $p$ and $q$. I don't really know how I could determine the log-likelihood for these observations. I think that I simply don't understand what we're observing: are these pairs $(R,M)$ of results and money or an $n$-tuple of results + a total money value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_n\stackrel{\mathrm{i.i.d.}}\sim\mathrm{Ber}(1-p)$, then $X = \inf\{n>0: X_n = 0\}$ has a geometric distribution: $\mathbb P(X=k) = (1-p)^k p$ for $k=0,1,2,\ldots$. We compute the mean of $X$:
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[X] &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty k\cdot\mathbb P(X=k)\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty k(1-p)^kp\\
&= p(1-p)\sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1)(1-p)^k\\
&= \frac {p(1-p)}{p^2}\\
&= \frac{1-p}p
\end{align}
and the second factorial moment:
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[X(X-1)] &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty k(k-1)\mathbb P(X=k)\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty k(k-1)(1-p)^kp\\
&= p(1-p)^2 \sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1)(k+2)(1-p)^k\\
&=\frac{2p(1-p)}{p^3}\\
&= \frac{2 (1-p)^2}{p^2}.
\end{align}
The variance of $X$ is then
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}(X) &= \mathbb E[X(X-1)] + \mathbb E[X] - \mathbb E[X]^2\\
&=\frac{2 (1-p)^2}{p^2}+\frac{1-p}p-\left(\frac{1-p}{p}\right)^2\\
&=\frac{1-p}{p^2}.
\end{align}
Conditioned on $\{X=n\}$, $Y$ is binomially distributed with parameters $n$ and $q$. So for each nonnegative integer $m$, we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(Y=m) &= \sum_{n=m}^\infty \mathbb P(Y=m\mid X=n)\mathbb P(X=n)\\
&= \sum_{n=m}^\infty \binom nm q^m(1-q)^{n-m}(1-p)^np\\
&= \frac{p (1-p)^m q^m}{ (p+q -pq)^{m+1}}.
\end{align}
We compute the mean of $Y$ by conditioning on $X$:
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[Y] &= \mathbb E[\mathbb E[Y\mid X]]\\
&= \mathbb E[qX]\\
&= q\mathbb E[X]\\
&= \frac{q(1-p)}p.
\end{align}
The variance of $Y$ is given by the law of total variance:
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}(Y) &= \mathbb E[\operatorname{Var}(Y\mid X)] + \operatorname{Var}(\mathbb E[Y\mid X])\\
&=\mathbb E[q(1-q)X] + \operatorname{Var}(qX)\\
&=q(1-q)\mathbb E[X] + q^2\operatorname{Var}(X)\\
&=\frac{q(1-q)(1-p)}p + \frac{q^2(1-p)}{p^2}\\
&= \frac{(1-p) \left(pq+q^2-pq^2\right)}{p^2}.
\end{align}